# @font-face printing issue in Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

First off, apologies if this is a simple thing, but I did a search here after googling and came up with nothing concrete: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[%40font-face]+print%2C+firefox

I have generated an @font-face kit with font squirrel with two licensed open type fonts. The demo works fine in all browsers except for 1 issue. I want the font to print, and it does for IE, but printing the document in Firefox 3.6.12 & Chrome 8.0.552.215.

Should the FS demo font be printable in FF and GC or is this impossible to do?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `@media print`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is currently possible in firefox, seems to completely disregard the fontface feature.

It's not just this though, seems to disregard background colour css (as do all apart from opera currently).

Spacing seems a little worse in firefox too, more bunched up.

Seems to have an issue with strong tags.

Answer (score 0):

Been having a similar problem and starting to think the issue in with Firefox.  A few things seem to point to it being a bug in the 3.6.13 version, but it is also possible that the font file has an invalid cmap problem as Firefox stopped rendering those as of 3.5.4.

More Info:

http://support.mozilla.com/ak/questions/769971

http://support.mozilla.com/sq/questions/761014

invalid cmap problem:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=526869